# Handle large hashtable in android

Tags: android, hashtable, out-of-memory

I have a problem when try to use `hashtable` with large data. I have a text file that contains over 111000 record, and when it reach 75000, **outofmemory exception** was thrown, so does anyone have any solution for this?

The problem happen at the line :

```
while ((text = reader.readLine())!= null);
```

and because of the  `java.lang.String <init>` inside the `readLine()`, but I think the problem come from the `hashtable` too big to keep store data. 
I tested it on my *xperia Neo* and it failed although it run quite good on another *samsung* device.

The object `SoundUnit` which I keep on `hashtable` has a structure below:

```
private String filename; 
private int start; 
private int end;
```

just above 3 field inside SoundUnit object.

Here is the piece of code I use to read data from text to store on `hashtable`:

```
       reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(unitSelectionFile),  "UTF-8"));
       String text=null;

       do {

                if (text.length() != 0) {
                    if (mainHash.get(text)==null)
                        mainHash.put(key, soundUnit);
                }


        } while ((text = reader.readLine())!= null);
```

Comment: so you are running out of memory. you just might try to reduce the size of your keys first. and further, what are you trying to accomplish? maybe theres a better way.

Comment: Yeah, i use hashtable because of speed, the data in this hashtable is a dictionary, so i want to get the data a fast as possible, so that's why i don't choose the database or xml approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most likely the hashtable is simply to large. I did a test on a Galaxy Nexus, which is a rather new phone, and it ran out of memory after 230k entries, with unique keys and values about 8 chars long. I would suggest to put your data in a [database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) instead.

Your reader should not be an issue, since `BufferedReader` only uses a small amount of memory.

Comment: so how about the speed to query the data from database in comparison with hashtable ?. is it fast enough ?

Comment: Just make sure to use an index on your key, and performance will be quite close to a hastable. It won't be as fast, but for most uses you should never notice a difference. Also make sure when you write to the database to do all the writing in one transaction. It will decrease the write-time significantly.

Comment: Look like the only way i can do now

Answer (score 0):

You should get the InputStream from the response and pass it to any xml handler for parsing it. This  should do the trick because by doing this your xml will be parsing dynamically as you get the inputstream.

Comment: I don't get it here, could you talk about it more specifically ?

Comment: Possibly you are getting InputStream from the response, you can use that InputStream to parse that xml using SAX Parser.